# Write nifti file from dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, voxel, nifti

I'm new to R and am trying to convert a data frame to a nifti file.  I have a data frame with 4 columns, the first 3 are for the dimensions (the voxels) and the 4th is for the values I want to write in the nifti file at the voxels.

I'm assuming I could use the writeNifti functions from either the fmri package or from RNifti, but they won't accept a raw data frame.  And I don't know how to get the data into an acceptable format that these packages will accept.

Any suggestions would be would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I used to write a Nifti file for a matrix `M` with dimensions (n^3/4,4):

```
# write nifti file ####
# I can't use neuroim::writeVolume because My RAM is not sufficient.
# Here is a workaround.
writeNifti <- function(voxel, n, fileName, dataType = NULL){
  vol <- neuroim::BrainVolume(numeric(2*2*2),
                               neuroim::BrainSpace(c(2,2,2), c(1,1,1)))
  vol@source@metaInfo@Dim <- vol@space@Dim <- c(n,n,n)
  hdr <- neuroim:::as.nifti.header(vol, vol@source@metaInfo)
  if (!is.null(dataType) && dataType != vol@source@metaInfo@dataType) {
    hdr$datatype <- neuroim:::.getDataCode(dataType)
    hdr$dataStorage <- neuroim:::.getDataStorage(hdr$datatype)
    hdr$bitpix <- neuroim:::.getDataSize(dataType) * 8
  }
  else {
    dataType <- vol@source@metaInfo@dataType
    hdr$datatype <- neuroim:::.getDataCode(dataType)
    hdr$dataStorage <- neuroim:::.getDataStorage(hdr$datatype)
    hdr$bitpix <- neuroim:::.getDataSize(dataType) * 8
  }
  conn <- if (substr(fileName, nchar(fileName) - 2, nchar(fileName)) == 
              ".gz") {
    gzfile(fileName, open = "wb")
  }
  else {
    file(fileName, open = "wb")
  }
  neuroim:::writeNIfTIHeader(hdr, conn, close = FALSE)
  writer <- neuroim::BinaryWriter(conn, hdr$voxOffset, dataType, hdr$bitpix/8, 
                         .Platform$endian)
  for(i in 1:ncol(voxel)){
    print(i)
    neuroim::writeElements(writer, voxel[,i])
  }
  neuroim::close(writer)
}

writeNifti(M, n, "myniftifile.nii.gz")
```

I don't remember the details.

Comment: Interesting, what do you mean when you say "dimensions (n^3/4,4)"?